don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.RangeList.setBorder
I'm writing a Google Apps Script on a Google Sheet. I want to set border on a range.
Here is my simple code that recorded by Macro feature in Google Sheet.
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
};

When I run it, it will show up the following error:

Error: The parameters (Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.RangeList.setBorder.


I checked the docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal,-color,-style
I think it should be right. I don't know why it's not working.

Is that all the code you have in the script?

Yes, there are exactly my code in the script.

Well, it's weird: it's working fine for me... except one time. I have got that same error, but only once; I don't know what I changed afterwards and I'm not able to replicate it. In any case, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID shouldn't be a number.

You might try lacing a SpreadsheetApp.flush() after the activate.

The code doesn't make sense. It already has the range reference as a literal then there is no need to actívate the range and use geActiveRangeList; just use getRange

How does getActiveRangeList () or Range List works in Apps Script.
The issue is coming from the fact that ActiveRangeList, is expecting a List of Ranges. However, the way you select range to be activated only produces a Range and will provide inconsistent results. by replicating your concern, and testing these proposed changes I was able to run it consistently.If there are scenario that you will have a list of range to run this code I suggest creating a Range checker if it the range provided or activated is just a Range or a Range List for a better result.
Script used
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
};


Reference

getActiveRange


It is strange though, as the documentation does specify "If there is a single range selected, this behaves as a getActiveRange() call.", and the thrown error doesn't involve using a Range method on a list, but rather a 'TypeError' in the SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle argument.

I do understand what you are saying, and I am with you on that one. I think that it is a little bit weird. I just provided where I get some more consistent success on my replication process. I think that raising this to issuetracker.google.com is another path to go just to clarify if this is an ongoing bug.

It do works. It seems a bug from Google.

Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you
